# Grab only required characters from http api

Tags: php, api

I collect data from http api and one of the api is to check balance of my remaining credits. Here is what I want to do, fetch file_contents and insert that remaining credits from the received output.

```
        $bal =  file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/balancecheck.php?username=123&api_password=123");
```

this outputs data like this

```
username = 123
validity = 31/03/2103
remaining credits = 5000
user credits = 3000
```

Now, I want to grab only 5000 (which is remaining credits and insert the same to my db)

I wanted to use explode but no luck. Please could someone help

Comment: what format is the return? exactly like that?

Comment: @David Nguyen it gives simple html reponse, when i view the souce it is like above with <br>

Comment: @Alasjo, I have not tried anything, as from different api, it oly gives balance credit which i easily update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> Description
>
> `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )`
>   Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.

So, what you need is:

```
preg_match( "/remaining credits = (\d+)/", file_get_contents($url), $matches);
$balance = $matches[1];
```

### Edit:

I had an extra `$` before the `file_get_contents` function call. I thought PHP made you put dollar signs everywhere. It should be fixed now.

### Edit 2:

I had `$balance = $matches[0]` before, but it has been corrected. The parentheses `(\d+)` captures just the number as a match and adds that to the end of the `$matches` array.

Comment: perfect, it gave me remaining credits = 5000. Now I have to trim "remaining sms =" and only insert balance. Is there a way to trim those words in that function?

Comment: by the way, i used this $balance = substr("$balance", 178, -31); but I got what i wanted but not stable as if any number increases then whole math will be wrong. Thanks for your time

Comment: Oh, I know what I did wrong. The `(\d+)` is supposed to catch the number as its own value, but I guessed wrong as to where it shows up in the array. Try `$balance = $balances[1]`.

Comment: genius, perfect, thanks so much. I already voted up and +1ed. Thanks again very much :)

Comment: Yeah, I try to go the extra mile.